# problema al conectar api con sql server

Tags: sql, asp.net-web-api, webapi

hola buenas quería ver si me ayudaban a resolver este error.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Filters.ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter' has been registered.
```

este es el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

básicamente intento conectar una base de datos a mi humilde api

este es mi modelo

```
public class Provedor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe Ingresar una Cedula")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[1-9]-\d{4}-\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "La Cedula se Digita en Formato #-####-####")]
    public string Cedula { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Descripcion del Proveedor")]
    [StringLength(150, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "Debe dar una Descripcion")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe de DIgitar")]
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
}
```

aqui tengo mi dbContext

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base (options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Provedor> Provedor { get; set; }

}
```

esta es mi conexion a mi appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=DESKTOP-UGCS31R\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=Proyecto3UNED; integrated security=true; trustServerCertificate=true"
  },

  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

si no agrego esto (trustServerCertificate=true) me genera otro error que dice que el certificado no es confiable.

aqui esta mi controlador donde ingreso un objeto del tipo provedor

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("create")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Cedula,Descripcion")] Provedor provedor)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _context.Add(provedor);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(provedor);
    }
```

Sinceramente e googleado bastante pero no entiendo que genera el problema, cualquier ayuda lo agradesco.

Comment: Es un problema de autentificación

Comment: O/Y elimina este decorador [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621934/validateantiforgerytoken-purpose-explanation-and-example

Comment: a ok si ya vi gracias